# How to order nodes in Tikz mindmap

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I was just trying to use a tikz mindmap, but there is a problem. I can't figure out how to set the two children of node (1) left and right. There is always the 60° spacing between them, I want them to be separated by 180°.

I tried level distance, `grow=left` and `right` etc. but nothing worked. 
I do not want change the whole child order, just the one for the node at the top.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
    node[concept] {\normalsize{Reibungsreduktion am Ventiltrieb}}
    [clockwise from=30]
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {5}
      [clockwise from=60]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a}} }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b} }}
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{c} }}
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {4}
      [clockwise from=0]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize a} }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b} } }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{c}} }
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {3}
      [clockwise from=-60]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a} }}
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b} }}
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{c} }}
    }  
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {2}
      [clockwise from=240]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a}} }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b}} }
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {6}
      [clockwise from=240]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a}} }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b}} }
    }
    child[concept color=blue] {
      node[concept] {1}
      [clockwise from=0]
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a}} }
      child { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b} }}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Code should be indented with 4 spaces; you can achieve this by marking the code and then pressing the `{}` icon above the edit box.

Comment: ahhhh. alright, thanks!
Any idea about the mindmap? How to arrange the nodes? I'm just not getting it... :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `[main/.style={sibling angle=180}]` to your `tikzpicture` like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[main/.style={sibling angle=180}]
```

Then you can write the part with the node `1` like:

```
...

child[concept color=blue] {
    node[concept] {1}
        [clockwise from =0]
    child[main] { node[concept] {\scriptsize{a}} }
    child[main] { node[concept] {\scriptsize{b} }}
};

...
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I humbly offer a small alternative:

```
child[grow=0] { node {a} }
child[grow=180] { node {b }}
```

together with

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        every node/.append style={concept},
        level 2 concept/.append style={node font=\scriptsize}]
```

which allows you not to have to specify each `node` as `concept` and not to have to specify `scriptsize` every time you're in a `level 2` node.

Here's the complete code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.append style={concept},
 level 2 concept/.append style={node font=\scriptsize}]
 \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
 node {\normalsize{Reibungsreduktion am Ventiltrieb}}
 [clockwise from=30]
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {5}
  [clockwise from=60]
  child { node {a} }
  child { node {b}}
  child { node {c}}
 }
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {4}
  [clockwise from=0]
  child { node {a} }
  child { node {b} }
  child { node {c} }
 }
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {3}
  [clockwise from=-60]
  child { node {a}}
  child { node {b}}
  child { node {c}}
 }  
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {2}
  [clockwise from=240]
  child { node {a} }
  child { node {b} }
 }
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {6}
  [clockwise from=240]
  child { node {a} }
  child { node {b} }
 }
 child[concept color=blue] {
  node {1}
  child[grow=0] { node {a} }
  child[grow=180] { node {b}}
 };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```